# How to block Bluetooth File Transfer on Windows

Tags: file, bluetooth, block, transfer

So I want to block file transfer on windows device. Solution should do following things:

1. Block bluetooth file transfer via all bluetooth transfer apps
2. Not block other devices like: headphones, mouse, keyboard, and other peripherals

I tried this, it doesn't work:

```
Modify the registry item

HKEYLOCALMACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\BTHPORT\Parameters
Value name DisableFsquirt
Value type REG_DWORD
Value data 0x1 (1)
```

Comment: Did you run: fsquirt.exe -UnRegister ?

Comment: Yes I tried that line after changing Registry

Comment: Try this to disable OPP service locally (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb870603(v=vs.85)). Not sure if that will work but you can try. Also you can simple disable discoverable and/or connectable so remote device can;'t find PC and connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

This registry setting only disable showing option **Bluetooth device** in "Send to" or **Send/Receive a file** over Bluetooth icon in taskbar.
But sending or receiving files are still possible via Bluetooth settings, or user can simply start fsquirt.exe.

If you use **Windows Enterprise** edition you can set **Applocker** to block **fsquirt.exe**.
Other devices should work normally, but sending/receiving files are blocked.